# deleting dynamically added DOM elements in IE6

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-6

My problem is that the  DELETE ITEM (Item which has been added dynamically) is not deleteing by click in IE6.

javascript:

```
var TDCount = 3;
var i=0;
function insertTD(){
        var possition=document.getElementById('elmnt_pos').value;
        if(possition=="")
        {
                    possition='a';
                    alert('Enter a number!!!');
         }
        if(isNaN(possition))
        {
          alert('Enter a number!!!');
          document.getElementById('elmnt_pos').value='';
        }else{
 var newTD = document.createElement("li");
        var newid='li'+TDCount++;
           newTD.setAttribute("id", newid);
           newTD.setAttribute("onclick","javascript:removenode(this);" );   
 var newText = document.createTextNode(i+"New fruit " + (possition++));
 newTD.appendChild(newText);

 var trElm = document.getElementById("menu");
 var refTD = trElm.getElementsByTagName("li").item(possition-2);
 trElm.insertBefore(newTD,refTD);
        i++;
        }

}
function removenode(th)
{
answer = confirm("Do you really want to Remove Element "+th.id + " ? ")
        if (answer !=0)
        {
        document.getElementById('menu').removeChild(document.getElementById(th.id));
        }

}
```

html

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="li0" onclick="javascript:removenode(this);">apple</li>
    <li id="li1" onclick="javascript:removenode(this);">Banana</li>
    <li id="li2" onclick="javascript:removenode(this);">Jackfruit</li>
</ul>
<form name="justfrm">
    <input type="text" value="Enter the position" name="pos1" id="elmnt_pos" />
    <input type="button" value="click" onclick="javascript:insertTD()"/>
</form>
```

"Enter the position" means add element on a specific position like 2,3,5 etc.
We can  Delete Item by click on item .

Comment: please, use the code button (the one with the binary digits) so your code doesn't look horrible

Comment: Please try to edit your code sample so it only contains the relevant parts. And do some kind of formatting on it - this is hurting my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an instance on Internet Explorer 6 to test with, but more than likely it's this line, which is causing the problem:

```
newTD.setAttribute("onclick","javascript:removenode(this);" );
```

It does not work in Internet Explorer 6. You will need to do something like:

```
newTD.onclick = function() { removeNode(this); };
```

or

```
newTD.onclick = new Function("removenode(this)");
```

See this [article](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/08/bug-242-setattribute-doesnt-always-work.html) for more information. Also, as a side note you may want to look into using a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), which already handles these types of cross-browser issues.

Comment: Thank you so much for you information .I just replace the 
newTD.setAttribute("onclick","javascript:removenode(this);" );
BY
newTD.onclick = new Function("removenode(this)");

and it's working perfect ...

Thanks a lot.