# javascript remove functionality is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, forms

I am working with dynamic textbox. when someone click on `"Add Option"` then textbox will be added dynamically. and when click on `"Remove"` the textbox will be removed dynamically. all the code of it is working fine with all browsers but `"Remove"` function is not working in IE 7

please help me regarding this issue

this is the javascript code

```
function addFormField()
{
  var optionId = $("#optionId").val();
  $("#pollOption").append("<p id='row" + optionId + "'><label for='txt" + optionId + "'>Option : <input type='text' size='20' name='option_"+optionId+"' id='option_"+optionId+"' name='option_"+optionId+"' class='text_field pollOption' validate='required:true'  \/> <a href='#' onclick='removeFormField(\"#row" + optionId + "\"); return false;'>Remove<\/a><\/br><\/p>");
  optionId = (parseInt(optionId) + 2) - 1;
  $("#optionId").val(optionId);
}

function removeFormField(optionId)
{
  $(optionId).remove();
  optionId = (parseInt(optionId) + 1) - 2;
}
$.validator.setDefaults(
{
  errorClass:"fontColorRed",
  submitHandler: function()
  {
    setPoll();
    return false;
  }
});
```

HTML code

```
<div class="pollContent">
        <div class="pollQuestionLable">
          Your poll Question </div>
        <div class="pollQuestionText">
          <input type="text" id="pollQuestion" class="text_field" name="pollQuestion" />
          <br/><a href="javascript:addFormField();">Add Options</a>
        </div>
        <div class="clearBoth"></div>
        <div class="pollQuestionLable">
          Poll Option
        </div>
        <div class="pollQuestionText">
          <div id="pollOption">
            <input type="hidden" id="optionId" value="3" />
            <p id='row1'>Option : <input type="text" id="option_1" name="option_1" class="text_field pollOption" validate='required:true' /></p>
            <p id='row2'>Option : <input type="text" id="option_2" name="option_2" class="text_field pollOption" validate='required:true' /></p>
          </div>
          <span id="ii" style="float:right">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="image" src="{$GLOBLE_PATH_REL}/images/share_bt.gif" />
          </span>
          <div class="wallPostToIcon4" id="wallPostToIcon4">
            <span class="sharingLockLeft" id="share" ><img src="{$GLOBLE_PATH_REL}/images/lock13.jpeg" border="0" alt="Share1" title="Share" /></span>
            <span class="sharingLockRight">&#9660;</span>
          </div>
          <div class="wallPostToPoll" id="wallPostToPoll">
            <ul>
              <li id="wallEveryOnePoll" value="1">Everyone</li>
              <li id="wallAllFriendsPoll" value="2">Friends of Friends</li>
              <li id="wallOnlyFriendsPoll" value="3">Friends Only</li>
              <li id="wallCustomizePoll" value="4">Customize</li>
             </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearBoth"></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but why the `(parseInt(optionId) + 1) - 2`? Why don't you just use: `parseInt(optionId) - 1`?

Comment: @Cerbrus additionally, this line is completely useless. optionId is scoped, and not used after this assignment, so it's effectively dead code.

Comment: i have tried but its not working @Cerbrus

Comment: @Christoph: You're right! How could I have missed that? :P
PrinceBijvani: Like I said, my comment is unrelated to the actual problem.

Comment: The problem might be that your IDs start with a number, which is not allowed in HTML <5, so IE7 might not select the element because of the invalid `ID`.

Comment: @Christoph, aren't the IDs like `row1` and `option_1`?

Comment: @Christoph ID start with number but it is initialize by row1, row2, etc

Comment: @PrinceBijvani, can you please post the full html/jsfiddle here or, at least, give a link to it?

Comment: @unclenorton i have added it above

Comment: @unclenorton according to the `addFormField()` function - yes. According to the `removeFormField()` most likely no because there is just a `$(optionId)` and `parseInt()` on a string starting with something else than a number always yields `NaN` so this only makes sense if it's starting with a number... EDIT: `removeFormField(\"#row" + optionId + "\");` makes it clear, it's not starting with a number.

Comment: can you both please help me regarding this? what can i do to resolve it?

Comment: all web browser display same id in code #row3, #row4, etc
but remove function not working in IE :(

Comment: well, except for that invalid id, i have no clue why it should not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but your problem might come from the invalid html code you append to `#pollOption`. I refer to the `<label>` element you open and never close. And probably some other things I didn't see.

The fundamental problem here is that I didn't see those. I don't see them because your code is hardly readable and therefore prone to errors of various kinds. (evident also in the comment section of your question, people talk about "Oh, I missed that..").

I don't want to sound mean, but your code smells. (this isn't offensive: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)).

```
window.optionId = 2;

window.addFormField = function() {
    optionId += 1;
    var thisOption = $('<p>', {
        'id': 'row' + optionId
    }).append(
        $('<label>').attr({
            'for': 'txt' + optionId
        }).html('Option : '), 
        $('<input>').attr({
            'type': 'text',
            'size': 20,
            'name': 'option_' + optionId,
            'class': 'text_field pollOption',
            'validate': 'required:true'
        }), 
        $('<a>').attr({
            'href': '#'
        }).html('Remove').click(function() {
            thisOption.remove();
        })
    ).appendTo('#pollOption');
};

$.validator.setDefaults(
{
  errorClass:"fontColorRed",
  submitHandler: function()
  {
    setPoll();
    return false;
  }
});
```

I refactored your `addFormField` function:

- I let jQuery construct the elements, this way no invalid markup is ever generated or used.
- I embedded the remove function, so I can directly refer to the element I want to remove (without having to search for it in the DOM).
- `optionId` is now an `Number` variable you can simply increment (without any parsing).

This refactored code surely still smells, because of encapsulation issues (global variables everywhere!) and others, but I think it's more readable and little bit more robust.

Comment: great, you have solved my problem, thank you very much @Roman

Answer (score 0):

I didn' understand few parts in your code. But I would suggest, if you are havving problems removing the element in IE, give this a try.

[Description says it worked.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439822/dom-element-delete-promlem-i-ie6)

And there is always an option of setting innerHTML of that div to ""(empty string). I know thats not good, but the last thing that can be tried.

Comment: He possibly only wants one `<p>` removed, so he cannot set innerHTML of the parent div to `""`.